# Difference between trigger threshold and metric_trigger threshold in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, appinsights

I was adding metric alerts to monitor a web api hosted in AKS and was looking `azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert`  [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert#metric_trigger). I could not tell the difference between the two thresholds. I am confused about the purpose and where each one applies ?

```
trigger {
    operator  = "GreaterThan"
    threshold = 3
    metric_trigger {
      operator            = "GreaterThan"
      threshold           = 1
      metric_trigger_type = "Total"
      metric_column       = "operation_Name"
    }
  }
```

Comment: did you get any answer? I am exactly looking for the same.

Comment: sadly no. Please post your answer if you figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tested with trial and error and found that metric_trigger's threshold maps to "minFailingPeriodsToAlert". AKA "how many times the threshold must be exceeded for the alert to fire".

We applied an alert with a trigger like this:

```
trigger {
    operator  = "GreaterThan"
    threshold = 3
    metric_trigger {
        metric_trigger_type = "Total"
        operator = "GreaterThanOrEqual"
        threshold = 100
        metric_column = "fileCount"
    }
}
```

and it created this resource in Azure

```
"criteria": {
    "allOf": [
        {
            "query": "customEvents | where parsedStatus != \"RUNNING\" and parsedStatus != \"SUCCESS\" ",
            "timeAggregation": "Average",
            "metricMeasureColumn": "AggregatedValue",
            "dimensions": [
                {
                    "name": "itemCount",
                    "operator": "Include",
                    "values": [
                        "*"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "operator": "GreaterThan",
            "threshold": 3,
            "failingPeriods": {
                "numberOfEvaluationPeriods": null,
                "minFailingPeriodsToAlert": 100
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

In the end we set metric_trigger's threshold to 0 and use the "regular" threshold for configuring our alert. I might use this setting if our application got bursts of traffic - it would let the server process the backlog of files without firing the alert immediately.

Comment: Thank you kind stranger for answering !